# ATR Trailing Stop needs to be reset on each long/short entry

Tags: pine-script

ATR Trailing Stop needs to be reset on each long/short entry because it's being updated once it reaches higher value. How do I do that?

If you add "3Commas Bot" on TradingView, I want to do the same: take profit, static stop loss and trailing stop loss.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Swing Strategy - Long/Short only", overlay = true)

// —————————— Constants {
// ————— Input options
var string GP1 = "Swing Settings"
var string GP2 = "Filters"
var string GP3 = "Stop Loss Settings"
var string GP4 = "Risk Management"

var string SLO1 = "High/Low"
var string SLO2 = "Close"
var string SLO3 = "Open"

// ————— Color constants
var color C_RED             = color.red
var color C_ORANGE          = color.orange
var color C_GREEN           = color.green
var color C_MAROON          = color.maroon
var color C_LIME            = color.lime
var color C_AQUA            = color.aqua
var color C_FUCHSIA         = color.fuchsia
// }

// —————————— Inputs {
// ————— Swing Settings
i_src                       = input(close, title = "Source", group = GP1)
i_samplingPeriod            = input(9, title = "Sampling Period", minval = 1, group = GP1)
i_rangeMultiplier           = input(1.9, title = "Range Multiplier", minval = 0.1, group = GP1)

// ————— Filters
i_useTimeRangeFilter        = input(false, title = "Use Time Range Filter", group = GP2)
i_startTime                 = input(timestamp("01 Jan 2021 00:00"), title = "Start Date/Time", type = input.time, group = GP2)
i_endTime                   = input(timestamp("01 Oct 2021 00:00"), title = "End Date/Time", type = input.time, group = GP2)

var bool inDate = i_useTimeRangeFilter ? (time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime) : true

// ————— Stop Loss Settings
i_useTrailingStop           = input(true, "Use ATR Trailing Stop", group = GP3)
i_atrLength                 = input(14, "ATR Trailing Length", group = GP3)
i_atrTrailingSource         = input(SLO1, "ATR Trailing Stop Source", options = [SLO1, SLO2, SLO3], group = GP3)
i_atrMultiplier             = input(1.5, "ATR Multiplier", step = 0.1, group = GP3)
i_swingLookback             = input(5, "Swing Lookback", group = GP3)

// ————— Risk Management
i_riskPerTrade              = input(2, "Risk Per Trade (%)", group = GP4) * 0.01
// }

// —————————— Functions {
// ————— Function used to calculate the Smooth Average Range
f_smoothAverageRange(src, t, m) =>
    wper = t * 2 - 1
    avrng = ema(abs(src - src[1]), t)
    smoothrng = ema(avrng, wper) * m
    smoothrng
    
// ————— Function used to calculate the Range Filter
f_rangeFilter(src, r) =>
    rngfilt = src
    rngfilt := src > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? src - r < nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : src - r : 
       src + r > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : src + r
    rngfilt
// }
    
// —————————— Calculations {
// ————— Swing
smrng = f_smoothAverageRange(i_src, i_samplingPeriod, i_rangeMultiplier)
filt = f_rangeFilter(i_src, smrng)

// Filter Direction
var float upward = na
upward := filt > filt[1] ? nz(upward[1]) + 1 : filt < filt[1] ? 0 : nz(upward[1])

var float downward = na
downward := filt < filt[1] ? nz(downward[1]) + 1 : filt > filt[1] ? 0 : nz(downward[1])

// Target Bands
hband = filt + smrng
lband = filt - smrng
// }

// —————————— Strategy Calls {
var bool longCond = na
longCond := i_src > filt and i_src > i_src[1] and upward > 0 or 
   i_src > filt and i_src < i_src[1] and upward > 0

var bool shortCond = na
shortCond := i_src < filt and i_src < i_src[1] and downward > 0 or 
   i_src < filt and i_src > i_src[1] and downward > 0

var int condIni = na
condIni := longCond ? 1 : shortCond ? -1 : condIni[1]
longCondition = longCond and condIni[1] == -1
shortCondition = shortCond and condIni[1] == 1

// TODO
atr             = atr(i_atrLength)
lowestLow       = lowest(low, i_swingLookback)
highestHigh     = highest(high, i_swingLookback)

FLAT            = strategy.position_size == 0
LONG            = strategy.position_size > 0
SHORT           = strategy.position_size < 0
entry           = strategy.position_avg_price

var float trailingStop = na

if LONG and i_useTrailingStop and barstate.isconfirmed
    trail = lowestLow - atr * i_atrMultiplier
    needsUpdate = trail > nz(trailingStop, 0)
    trailingStop := needsUpdate ? trail : trailingStop

if SHORT and i_useTrailingStop and barstate.isconfirmed
    trail = highestHigh + atr * i_atrMultiplier
    needsUpdate = trail < nz(trailingStop, 0)
    trailingStop := needsUpdate ? trail : trailingStop

plot(entry, "Entry Price", color.gray, style = plot.style_linebr)
plot(trailingStop, "Stop Price", color.red, style = plot.style_linebr)

// Long
strategy.entry("LONG", strategy.long, when = longCondition)
// strategy.exit("EXIT LONG", "LONG", stop = i_useTrailingStop ? trailingStop : 0)

// Short
strategy.entry("SHORT", strategy.short, when = shortCondition)
// strategy.exit("EXIT SHORT", "SHORT", stop = i_useTrailingStop ? trailingStop : 0)
// }

// —————————— Plots {
// ————— Swing
barcolor = i_src > filt and i_src > i_src[1] and upward > 0 ? C_LIME : 
   i_src > filt and i_src < i_src[1] and upward > 0 ? C_GREEN : 
   i_src < filt and i_src < i_src[1] and downward > 0 ? C_RED : 
   i_src < filt and i_src > i_src[1] and downward > 0 ? C_MAROON : C_ORANGE
barcolor(barcolor)

filtcolor = upward > 0 ? C_LIME : downward > 0 ? C_RED : C_ORANGE
p_filtplot = plot(filt, title = "Range Filter", color = filtcolor, linewidth = 3)

// Target
p_hbandplot = plot(hband, title = "High Target", color = color.new(C_AQUA, 90))
p_lbandplot = plot(lband, title = "Low Target",  color = color.new(C_FUCHSIA, 90))

// Fills
fill(p_hbandplot, p_filtplot, color = color.new(C_AQUA, 90),    title = "High Target Range")
fill(p_lbandplot, p_filtplot, color = color.new(C_FUCHSIA, 90), title = "Low Target Range")

plotshape(longCondition,  title = "Buy Signal",  style = shape.labelup,   location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, text = "BE",  textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)
plotshape(shortCondition, title = "Sell Signal", style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color = color.red,   text = "SE",  textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)
// }

// —————————— Backtester {
float totalTrades = strategy.closedtrades
float winrate = (strategy.wintrades / strategy.closedtrades) * 100

var table tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 6, border_width = 3)

f_fillCell(_tbl, _column, _row, _text, _bgcolor, _textcolor) =>
    table.cell(_tbl, _column, _row, _text, bgcolor = _bgcolor, text_color = _textcolor)
    
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    color bgcolor = color.new(color.gray, 80)
    color textcolor = color.gray
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 0, str.format("Total Trades\n{0,number,integer}", totalTrades), bgcolor, textcolor)
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 1, str.format("Win Rate\n{0,number,#.##}%", winrate), bgcolor, textcolor)
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 2, str.format("Return of Investment\n{0,number,#.##}%", 0), bgcolor, textcolor)
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 3, str.format("Risk of Ruin\n{0,number,#.##}%", 0), bgcolor, textcolor)
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 4, str.format("Kelly Criterion\n{0,number,#.##}%", 0), bgcolor, textcolor)
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 5, str.format("Start Time\n{0,date,yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss}", i_startTime), bgcolor, textcolor)
// }
```

Comment: Can you explain the issue a little bit in more details? What is happening at the moment and what do you want to happen? Maybe with a screenshot too.

Comment: @BarisYakut, https://i.imgur.com/lMKW2e3.png. Look at the red line. It should be drawn from each Long/Short to the exit and it should also update the ATR value only if it's a higher value. You can add "3Commas Bot" script into your TradingView and you can see how it performs there. I'm trying to do exactly the same but with simpler code that I can understand.

Comment: And by red line do you mean the line that goes through candlestick bars that sometimes becomes green and sometimes red? Or the one below candlesticks? I have recently decided to write my own strategy for 3commas DCA bots, so I will definitely have a look.

Comment: @Baris Yakut, it doesn't just become red or green, it's because it changes from long to short etc. The green line is the take profit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Nop since we are incorporating "3commas bot" this was easier to migrate your entry conditions to the template, rather than fix the problems with this one. This way you get all the added options of the original, with your own custom strategy. Notice here we can set a limit, a trail, or we can isolate trades by not allowing reversal trades or allowing them. Essentially it is your strategy with flexibilities that offer you a suite of backtesting capability. Here is the code I just copy pasted in your magic over top of the ma cross section of the original.

```
// ███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██████╗░
// ████╗░██║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
// ██╔██╗██║██║░░██║██████╔╝
// ██║╚████║██║░░██║██╔═══╝░
// ██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░░░░
// ╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░░░░

//@version=4
 
strategy("Swing Strategy - Long/Short only", "Swing Strategy", true, precision=3, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, commission_value= 0.05, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, slippage=1, currency=currency.USD, default_qty_value= 10000, initial_capital= 10000)

// ================================== //
// ---------> Tool Time <------------ //
// ================================== //

longTradesTip           = "Turn on/off long trades. Perhaps you are overall bearish and wish to exempt long trades on this asset"  
shortTradesTip          = "Turn on/off short trades. Perhaps you are overall bullish and wish to exempt long trades on this asset"
useLimitTip             = "Turns on/off the limit exit method. eg: using trail and not setting a limit exit. Must use trail, or strategy has no exit criteria"
trailStopTip            = "Turns on/off the ATR trailing stop exit method." 
FLIPTip                 = "Allows a reversal trade. eg. flipping short from a long pos. False will isolate trades from one another, while true allows an opposite bias entry while in a position already"
setMaxDrawdownTip       = "Enables max drawdown protection. Enabling this will stop the bot if the overall strategy drawdown drops below the defined risk appetite"
RnRTip                  = "This sets your risk to reward as a multiple. 1 is stop/limit equal distance from entry" 
RiskMTip                = "Multiplier as a function of the ATR value projected from the calculated swing high/low. This allows for a buffer for your stop placing it behind support/resistance for the lookback period"  
swinglookbackTip        = "This is your swing lookback. The the number of bars within the period calculated for lowest or highest value to establish a swing pivot"  
maxPercDdTip            = "Risk appetite. Every strategy sees downside. This is how much you could stomach to allow the bot to lose if you let it run. Strategy stops taking trades below this level" 
atrLenTip               = "Length of the period for the ATR to average"  
trailStopSizeTip        = "The ATR multiplier for ATR-based trailing stop. Higher number yields a higher volatility based risk adjustment from the swing low"
trailSourceTip          = "The price source for calculating ATR trailing stop"
rrExitTip               = "This is the % of reward (target price) that must hit in order to trigger the trail expressed as a decimal. eg. 0.5 = 50% to target."
maType1Tip              = "Sets the moving average type for the first MA" 
maType2Tip              = "Sets the moving average type for the second MA"
maLength1Tip            = "Sets the length for the first MA. (it is likely best to keep MA1 length less than MA2, or it may result in opposite trade bias desired depending on MA type"
maLength2Tip            = "Sets the length for the second MA. (it is likely best to keep MA2 length greater than MA2, or it may result in opposite trade bias desired depending on MA type"  
drawEntryTip            = "Shows the trade entry level"
exitLvlTip              = "Shows the level that the trailing stop is triggered"
useTimeFilterTip        = "Turns on/off time session filter"
timeSessionTip          = "Time session to ignore trades (useful for ignoring trades during times you don't want to trade. eg. Markets are slow for a period of time in the night)"
startTimeTip            = "Start date & time to begin backtest period. Also useful for beginning new bot. eg. Set time to now to make broker emulator in a flat position before setting alerts"
endTimeTip              = "End date & time to stop searching for setups for back testing."

// —————————— Constants {
// ————— Input options
var string GP1 = "Swing Settings"
var string GP2 = "Filters"
var string GP3 = "Stop Loss Settings"
var string GP4 = "Risk Management"

var string SLO1 = "High/Low"
var string SLO2 = "Close"
var string SLO3 = "Open"

// ————— Color constants
var color C_RED             = color.red
var color C_ORANGE          = color.orange
var color C_GREEN           = color.green
var color C_MAROON          = color.maroon
var color C_LIME            = color.lime
var color C_AQUA            = color.aqua
var color C_FUCHSIA         = color.fuchsia
// }

// ================================== //
// ---------> User Input <----------- //
// ================================== //

longTrades              = input(true,       "Detect Long Trades",                       input.bool,         group="Trade variables",    tooltip=longTradesTip)
shortTrades             = input(true,       "Detect Short Trades",                      input.bool,         group="Trade variables",    tooltip=shortTradesTip)
useLimit                = input(false,      "Use Limit exit",                           input.bool,         group="Trade variables",    tooltip=useLimitTip)   
trailStop               = input(true,       "Use ATR Trailing Stop",                    input.bool,         group="Trade variables",    tooltip=trailStopTip)  
FLIP                    = input(true,       "Allow Reversal Trades",                    input.bool,         group="Trade variables",    tooltip=FLIPTip)       
setMaxDrawdown          = input(false,      "Set Max Total DrawDown",                   input.bool,         group="Trade variables",    tooltip=setMaxDrawdownTip)  

RnR                     = input(1,          "Reward to Risk Ratio",                     input.float,        group="Risk Management",    tooltip=RnRTip,         minval=0)
RiskM                   = input(1,          "Risk Adjustment",                          input.float,        group="Risk Management",    tooltip=RiskMTip,       minval=0)
swinglookback           = input(5,          "Swing Lookback",                           input.integer,      group="Risk Management",    tooltip=swinglookbackTip) 
maxPercDd               = input(20,         "Max Drawdown (%)",                         input.integer,      group="Risk Management",    tooltip=maxPercDdTip)       
atrLen                  = input(14,         "ATR length",                               input.integer,      group="Risk Management",    tooltip=atrLenTip)          

trailStopSize           = input(1.0,        "ATR Trailing Stop Multiplier",             input.float,        group="Trailing Stop",      tooltip=trailStopSizeTip)
trailSource             = input("High/Low", "ATR Trailing Stop Source",                 input.string,       group="Trailing Stop",      tooltip=trailSourceTip, options=["High/Low", "Close", "Open"])
rrExit                  = input(0.0,        "R:R To Trigger Exit",                      input.float,        group="Trailing Stop",      tooltip=rrExitTip)

i_src                   = input(close,      "Source",                                                       group = GP1)
i_samplingPeriod        = input(9,          "Sampling Period",                          minval = 1,         group = GP1)
i_rangeMultiplier       = input(1.9,        "Range Multiplier",                         minval = 0.1,       group = GP1)

drawEntry               = input(true,       "Draw entry price",                         input.bool,         group="Display",            tooltip=drawEntryTip)
exitLvl                 = input(true,       "Draw trail trigger price",                 input.bool,         group="Display",            tooltip=exitLvlTip)

useTimeFilter           = input(false, "Use Time Session Filter",                       input.bool,         group="Filters",            tooltip=useTimeFilterTip)  
timeSession             = input("0000-0300", "Time Session To Ignore Trades",           input.session,      group="Filters",            tooltip=timeSessionTip)    
startTime               = input(timestamp("01 Jan 2000 00:00 GMT-7"), "Start Filter",   input.time,         group="Filters",            tooltip=startTimeTip)      
endTime                 = input(timestamp("01 Jan 2099 00:00 GMT-7"), "End Filter",     input.time,         group="Filters",            tooltip=endTimeTip)        

// ================================== //
// -----> Invariable Constants <----- //
// ================================== //

    // built in functions to make the script more readable when referencing position conditions //
    
FLAT                        = strategy.position_size == 0
LONG                        = strategy.position_size > 0
SHORT                       = strategy.position_size < 0
confirmed                   = barstate.isconfirmed
entry                       = strategy.position_avg_price

    // using the var function allows "saving" of values to be set later. This allows us to "set" a stop for example and not have it change as its recalcualted on each bar. //

var lookForExit             = false   
var tradeStopPrice          = 0.0
var tradeTargetPrice        = 0.0
var trailingStop            = 0.0
var tradeExitTriggerPrice   = 0.0
var tradeStopDistance       = 0.0
var tradeTriggerPrice       = 0.0

// ================================== //
// ---> Functional Declarations <---- //
// ================================== //

f_smoothAverageRange(src, t, m) =>
    wper = t * 2 - 1
    avrng = ema(abs(src - src[1]), t)
    smoothrng = ema(avrng, wper) * m
    smoothrng
    
// ————— Function used to calculate the Range Filter
f_rangeFilter(src, r) =>
    rngfilt = src
    rngfilt := src > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? src - r < nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : src - r : 
       src + r > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : src + r
    rngfilt
    
isInSession(sess) => na(time(timeframe.period, sess + ":1234567", "GMT-6")) == false

// ================================== //
// ----> Variable Calculations <----- //
// ================================== //

// —————————— Calculations {
// ————— Swing
smrng = f_smoothAverageRange(i_src, i_samplingPeriod, i_rangeMultiplier)
filt = f_rangeFilter(i_src, smrng)

// Filter Direction
var float upward = na
upward := filt > filt[1] ? nz(upward[1]) + 1 : filt < filt[1] ? 0 : nz(upward[1])

var float downward = na
downward := filt < filt[1] ? nz(downward[1]) + 1 : filt > filt[1] ? 0 : nz(downward[1])

// Target Bands
hband = filt + smrng
lband = filt - smrng
// }

atr                         = atr       (atrLen)

    // Calculate the swing high/ low. Takes the highest/ lowest point over the user defined lookback period
    
lowestLow                   = lowest    (low,  swinglookback)
highestHigh                 = highest   (high, swinglookback)

    // renders the time filter funciton and sets the date filter used for screeening out trades, or adjusting back test. 
    
timeFilter                  = (useTimeFilter and not isInSession(timeSession)) or not useTimeFilter
dateFilter                  = time >= startTime and time <= endTime

withinTime                  = timeFilter and dateFilter

// ================================== //
// ----> Conditional Parameters <---- //
// ================================== //

// —————————— Strategy Calls {
var bool longCond = na
longCond := i_src > filt and i_src > i_src[1] and upward > 0 or 
   i_src > filt and i_src < i_src[1] and upward > 0

var bool shortCond = na
shortCond := i_src < filt and i_src < i_src[1] and downward > 0 or 
   i_src < filt and i_src > i_src[1] and downward > 0

var int condIni = na
condIni := longCond ? 1 : shortCond ? -1 : condIni[1]
longCondition = longCond and condIni[1] == -1
shortCondition = shortCond and condIni[1] == 1

validLongEntry              = longCondition  and not na(atr) // assigns the cross conditon to each entry variable. 
validShortEntry             = shortCondition and not na(atr) // "and not na(atr)" is used to prevent entries at very beginning of the backtest before ATR can render over its 14 period lookback. 
                                                          // Stops and targets cannot calcualte in this period resulting in a broken strategy. Its reccomended to keep that with your own criteria. 
    // =================================== //
    
condmaxdrawdown             = setMaxDrawdown        ? maxPercDd         : 100 // used to set the max draw down, if used 

// ================================== //
// -------> Risk Mitigation <-------- //
// ================================== //

    // check what trail source was chosen, calcualte the trail price, check if its higher than last bar, assing new trail value
if LONG and trailStop and lookForExit and confirmed 
    trailSrcLong            = (trailSource == "Close" ? close[1] : trailSource == "Open" ? open[1] : lowestLow)
    trail                   = trailSrcLong - (atr * trailStopSize)
    needsUpdate             = trail > trailingStop
    trailingStop            := needsUpdate ? trail : trailingStop 

    // check what trail source was chosen, calcualte the trail price, check if its lower than last bar, assing new trail value
if SHORT and trailStop and lookForExit and confirmed
    trailSrcShort           = (trailSource == "Close" ? close[1] : trailSource == "Open" ? open[1] : highestHigh)
    trail                   = trailSrcShort + (atr * trailStopSize)
    needsUpdate             = trail < trailingStop
    trailingStop            := needsUpdate ? trail : trailingStop 
    
    ///     Calculate Stops      ///
 
longStop                    = lowestLow -   (atr*RiskM)
shortStop                   = highestHigh + (atr*RiskM)
 
longRisk                    = close -       longStop 
shortRisk                   = shortStop -   close
 
longlimit                   = close +       (RnR*longRisk)
shortlimit                  = close -       (RnR*shortRisk)

longLimitDist               = close -       longlimit
shortLimitDist              = shortlimit -  close

// ================================== //
// --------> Logical Order <--------- //
// ================================== //

    ///     Save Stops and set entries    ///
 
if validShortEntry and (FLAT or (LONG and FLIP)) and withinTime and shortTrades
    tradeStopPrice          := shortStop 
    tradeTargetPrice        := useLimit ? shortlimit : na 
    tradeExitTriggerPrice   := close + (shortLimitDist * rrExit)
    lookForExit             := false
    trailingStop            := tradeStopPrice
else
    validShortEntry         := false
 
if validLongEntry and (FLAT or (SHORT and FLIP)) and withinTime and longTrades
    tradeStopPrice          := longStop
    tradeTargetPrice        := useLimit ? longlimit : na 
    tradeExitTriggerPrice   := close - (longLimitDist  * rrExit)
    lookForExit             := false
    trailingStop            := tradeStopPrice
else
    validLongEntry          := false

    // check to see if the rrExit level was exceeded to trigger the trail. If not set then begin trail on entry 
if LONG and rrExit != 0.0 and (high >= tradeExitTriggerPrice and trailStop) or (rrExit == 0.0 and trailStop)
    lookForExit             := true
    
if SHORT and rrExit != 0.0 and (low <= tradeExitTriggerPrice and trailStop) or (rrExit == 0.0 and trailStop)
    lookForExit             := true

// ================================== //
// ------> Graphical Display <------- //
// ================================== //

    // draw orders if in trade, draw targets or triggers if not exceeded, only draw exit if within RnR boundary. Use draw orders offset to plot one bar before entry to make plot levels visible on first bar of trade 
    
drawOrders                  = (validLongEntry or validShortEntry) or not FLAT 
stopPrice                   = trailStop ? trailingStop : tradeStopPrice
targetPrice                 = lookForExit and not useLimit ? na : tradeTargetPrice
drawExit                    = SHORT and tradeExitTriggerPrice > targetPrice and tradeExitTriggerPrice < entry or 
                              LONG and tradeExitTriggerPrice < targetPrice and tradeExitTriggerPrice > entry 
plotExitPrice               = ((drawExit and trailStop) or (trailStop and not useLimit)) and (drawOrders or drawOrders[1]) and not lookForExit ? drawOrders ? tradeExitTriggerPrice : tradeExitTriggerPrice[1] : na
plotStopPrice               = drawOrders or drawOrders[1] ? drawOrders ? stopPrice   : stopPrice[1]   : na
plotTarget                  = drawOrders or drawOrders[1] ? drawOrders ? targetPrice : targetPrice[1] : na 

plot                        (drawEntry ? entry : na,        "Entry Price",          #9598a1,                        style=plot.style_linebr)
plot                        (exitLvl ? plotExitPrice : na,  "Trigger Exit",         color.blue,                     style=plot.style_linebr)
plot                        (plotStopPrice,                 "Stop Price",           color.red,                      style=plot.style_linebr)
plot                        (plotTarget,                    "Target Price",         color.green,                    style=plot.style_linebr)

    // color background if bars outside of time filter 
bgcolor                     (color=(useTimeFilter and isInSession(timeSession)) or not dateFilter ? color.new(color.red,80) : na, title="Filter Color")

// ================================== //
// --------> 3-Commas Keys <--------- //
// ================================== //

        // Paste your bot messages here. Make sure you keep single quotes ' on either side of your paste. example: ' paste ' //
        
        // ** SPECIAL NOTE ** Notice that for long and short entries ONLY there is a delay of 1 second. I noticed that flip trades can cause problems at 3commas causing it to miss orders, so a small delay allows things to run smoothly.
        // This is up to you, but be aware of it that it is an option to put in a delay to stagger the alerts slightly // 

Long        =  '    {  "message_type": "bot",  "bot_id": 4635591,  "email_token": "25byourtefcodeuufyd2-43314-ab98-bjorg224",  "delay_seconds": 1}  ' //start long deal
 
ExitLong    =  '    {  "message_type": "bot",  "bot_id": 4635591,  "email_token": "25byourtefcodeuufyd2-43314-ab98-bjorg224",  "delay_seconds": 0,  "action": "close_at_market_price"}  ' // close long deal market 
 
Goshort     =  '    {  "message_type": "bot",  "bot_id": 4635690,  "email_token": "25byourtefcodeuufyd2-43314-ab98-bjorg224",  "delay_seconds": 1}  ' // start short deal
 
ExitShort   =  '    {  "message_type": "bot",  "bot_id": 4635690,  "email_token": "25byourtefcodeuufyd2-43314-ab98-bjorg224",  "delay_seconds": 0,  "action": "close_at_market_price"}  ' // close short deal market

// ================================== //
// ------> Strategy Execution <------ //
// ================================== //

strategy.risk.max_drawdown (value=condmaxdrawdown, type=strategy.percent_of_equity)

    // lONG 
 
strategy.entry  (id="Long", long=true, when=validLongEntry, comment="Long", alert_message=Long)
 
strategy.exit   (id="Long Exit", from_entry="Long", stop=trailStop ? trailingStop : tradeStopPrice, limit=tradeTargetPrice, when=LONG, comment="L Exit",   alert_message=ExitLong)
 
    // SHORT  
 
strategy.entry  (id="Short", long=false, when=validShortEntry, comment="Short",   alert_message=Goshort)
 
strategy.exit   (id="Short Exit", from_entry="Short", stop=trailStop ? trailingStop : tradeStopPrice, limit=tradeTargetPrice, when=SHORT, comment="S Exit",   alert_message=ExitShort)
 
    // end deal if already in pos. This gives an extra alert to end a deal if reversal trades are allowed. Once per bar is fine becasue 'confirmed' used in entry criteria 
 
if validLongEntry and SHORT and FLIP
    alert       (ExitShort,         alert.freq_once_per_bar)
 
if validShortEntry and LONG and FLIP
    alert       (ExitLong ,          alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    
    
// —————————— Plots {
// ————— Swing
barcolor = i_src > filt and i_src > i_src[1] and upward > 0 ? C_LIME : 
   i_src > filt and i_src < i_src[1] and upward > 0 ? C_GREEN : 
   i_src < filt and i_src < i_src[1] and downward > 0 ? C_RED : 
   i_src < filt and i_src > i_src[1] and downward > 0 ? C_MAROON : C_ORANGE
barcolor(barcolor)

filtcolor = upward > 0 ? C_LIME : downward > 0 ? C_RED : C_ORANGE
p_filtplot = plot(filt, title = "Range Filter", color = filtcolor, linewidth = 3)

// Target
p_hbandplot = plot(hband, title = "High Target", color = color.new(C_AQUA, 90))
p_lbandplot = plot(lband, title = "Low Target",  color = color.new(C_FUCHSIA, 90))

// Fills
fill(p_hbandplot, p_filtplot, color = color.new(C_AQUA, 90),    title = "High Target Range")
fill(p_lbandplot, p_filtplot, color = color.new(C_FUCHSIA, 90), title = "Low Target Range")

plotshape(longCondition,  title = "Buy Signal",  style = shape.labelup,   location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, text = "BE",  textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)
plotshape(shortCondition, title = "Sell Signal", style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color = color.red,   text = "SE",  textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)
// }

// —————————— Backtester {
float totalTrades = strategy.closedtrades
float winrate = (strategy.wintrades / strategy.closedtrades) * 100

var table tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 6, border_width = 3)

f_fillCell(_tbl, _column, _row, _text, _bgcolor, _textcolor) =>
    table.cell(_tbl, _column, _row, _text, bgcolor = _bgcolor, text_color = _textcolor)
    
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    color bgcolor = color.new(color.gray, 80)
    color textcolor = color.gray
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 0, str.format("Total Trades\n{0,number,integer}", totalTrades), bgcolor, textcolor)
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 1, str.format("Win Rate\n{0,number,#.##}%", winrate), bgcolor, textcolor)
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 2, str.format("Return of Investment\n{0,number,#.##}%", 0), bgcolor, textcolor)
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 3, str.format("Risk of Ruin\n{0,number,#.##}%", 0), bgcolor, textcolor)
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 4, str.format("Kelly Criterion\n{0,number,#.##}%", 0), bgcolor, textcolor)
    f_fillCell(tbl, 0, 5, str.format("Start Time\n{0,date,yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss}", startTime), bgcolor, textcolor)
// }
```

Cheers and best of luck in your coding and trading

Comment: Thank you very much mate! Do I need to enable all boolean inputs in order to make the take profits and reversal trades work as intended?

Comment: yes if we want to isolate trades, you leave the reversal trades off, if you want a limit enabled as well, you enable limit orders etc